# Green sticker put on passport by VFS Delhi for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I submitted my application for UK Standard Visa at VFS centre in New Delhi and the desk executive collecting the documents put a green sticker on my pouch/passport. She had other color stickers too with her. Does/could this mean anything or am I overthinking?

Comment: could you show a picture of the sticker? redact any personal info if applicaple.

Comment: mobiles/ cameras not allowed inside the centre....so could not take picture

Answer (score 4):

> Does/Could this mean anything or am i overthinking?

It means absolutely nothing to you. That person has no bearing on the decision and can't even suggest *looks good* to the **ECO**.

Whatever the color of that sticker,  it is for their internal use and can not effect the outcome of this application.

If a [British Ambassador can not impact the outcome](https://blogs.fco.gov.uk/tomfletcher/2012/11/14/top-secret-how-to-get-a-uk-visa/), a VFS official certainly cant.